# Reclaiming partitions after old Linux installation

Tags: macos, hard-drive, disk-utility, partition, recovery

A long while back I recall installing Linux on my macbook. I have since deleted it, but the partitions on my disk are somewhat screwy. I cannot reclaim the free space to my main Macintosh HD partition (only to recovery).

Any ideas for how to reclaim it? If there is a way which wipes the drives I'm fine with that. See below picture and diskutil output.

Any and all advice welcome :)

[image: desc]

Showing that I can only resize to recovery:

[image: swsa]

````
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *121.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         86.2 GB    disk0s2
   3:                  Apple_HFS Recovery HD             800.0 MB   disk0s3

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +86.2 GB    disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD            48.1 GB    disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 45.0 MB    disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                510.4 MB   disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      1.1 GB     disk1s4```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With versions of macOS, which are installed in an APFS container, there is no need for a separate recovery partition. Therefore, you should be able to delete the recovery partition with the command given below.

```
diskutil erasevolume free none disk0s3
```

With the recovery partition deleted, you should be able to add the free space to the APFS container by using the command below.

```
diskutil apfs resizecontainer disk0s2 0
```

Comment: This resolved the issue. Many thanks. Made my day!